# Understanding Base case in Dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Consider this question [count of different ways express-n sum-1-3-4](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-ofdifferent-ways-express-n-sum-1-3-4/)

My understanding here is f(n) is number of ways to represent n as sum of 1, 3 and 4

f(n-1) is number of ways to represent n-1 as sum of 1, 3 and 4

f(1) is number of ways to express 1 as sum of  1, 3 and 4

f(0) is number of ways to express 0 as sum of  1, 3 and 4

should not that be 0 as there is no way to represent/express 0 as sum of 1,3,4

Just starting to learn Dynamic programming but I don't get why this should be 1 not 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well lets say you want to represent some sum S as sum of 1, 3 and 4

You can write this mathematically as equation `S = 1*x + 3*y + 4*z` where x,y,z denotes amounts of ones, threes and fours in the sum.

So now `f(S)` is just amount of solutions to the equation (having in mind that x,y,z are non-negative integers)

And when `S=0` we can easily see that equation has one solution - `x=0, y=0, z=0`

Comment: This problems also considers permutations. Only solving via equation gives you combinations.

Comment: The equation may be helpful to understand but as vivek_23 pointed out, `f(S)` in this answer may be a different function since it does not seem to address permutations.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are suggesting were correct, then we also could not count 1 + 1 + 1 as a way to express 3, since that sum does not include either a 3 or a 4.

Rather than the number of ways to "express n as a of sum of 1, 3 and 4," think of it as the number of arrangements of an optional selection of 1's, 3's and 4's that sum to n. Then there is only one such arrangement for target 0, which is to select none.